# To Use Conditional Operation on Textarea

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I want to show value of Comment in the text-area if it is not null. I tried with below code:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div id="details-container">        
        <table border="1">
        <tr style="width:50px">                
            <td>
                <textarea name="textarea" rows="4" cols="95">(#= Comment # != null)? #= Comment # : ' '</textarea>
            </td>                
        </tr>
    </div>
</script>
```

But the value comes in textarea as `(null != null)? null : ' '` instead of value. Can we use conditional operation on textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<textarea name="textarea" rows="4" cols="95">#= typeof Comment==='string'?Comment:'' #</textarea>
```

#### Why

U should put ur whole expression between the two "#".